# Notifications in Distributed Software C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, notifications, distributed-computing

I'm creating a windows forms application for notify when new job added to the system. The client software should notify when new job added. client software should be install more than one computers.

Currently I'm create a thread to check the database record count every second. when count is greater than previous count I'm firing a event. so it detects the new job added. But I think it is very overhead to the database. so that any one can give me the better solution to doing this thing.

Answer (score 0):

that may vary depending on your network environment ... a local area network? ... the internet?

LAN case: try multicast ... google yourself a c# multicast tutorial, let your client listen to multicast messages, and fire up events by multicasting to all the other clients ...

internet case: set up a server the client has to connect to ... register each client with a callback channel, and deliver events to the server ... let the server distribute them to all other connected clients

if you have too many clients ... same approach, but have multiple servers ...let the servers treat each other as clients and let them connect to each other ...

Answer (score 0):

In case of SQL server try to use
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx